# Can I update a JavaScript on mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a mobile site where I am using JavaScript to refresh a message counter, JavaScript is enabled but it does not update the counter. The phone I am testing on is a Nokia e90. the other test phone is an HTC innovation and it works perfect on there.

Is it a issue of the JavaScript version on the e90 is out of date?

Here is my JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title><?php echo TITLE_HOME;?></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- like this-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        refresh();
    });

    function refresh()
    {      
        $.get('newMessageCnt.php', function (cnt) {
        $("#msgcntDiv").html("You have " + cnt);
        //console.log(cnt);
        //$("#msgcntDiv").text("You have " + cnt);
        window.setTimeout(refresh,30000);
        });   
    }   
 </script>
```

and the php:

```
<?php
if ($numOfMessages <> 0)
{
    echo "<span class='headings_sub' id='msgcntDiv'>You have " .$numOfMessages . "</span>";
    echo "<a class='red_link' href='".ADDRESS."messages.php'> unopened Messages</a>";
}
else
{
     echo "<span class='headings_sub'>You have no new messages</span>";
}
?>
```

on the HTC `$numOfMessages` updates without a blink. On the E90 nothing happens

Comment: Please capitalise your I's next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and add the id to the else echo statement

```
else {
 echo "<span class='headings_sub' id='msgcntDiv'>You have no new messages</span>";
}
```

If you start with 0 messages then if other messages come you won't have a span id to update the text.

Answer (score 0):

Symbian s60v3 navigator is based in webkit engine and javascript engine also.
Not sure to be the root cause of your problem. Give us your code, it can help.

Comment: do you use jQuery or jQuery mobile? And which version ?

Comment: yes i see it in my directory: jquery.mobile-1.0b2 how do i change my code at the top then to include this please? thanks